# trying to make a scheme procedure

Tags: dictionary, scheme, mutability

trying to make a scheme procedure called make-odd-mapper! its supposed to be a procedure that takes one input, a procedure, and produces a procedure as an output

ex:

> (define i4 (mlist 10 2 30 4))
>
> (i4)

{10 2 30 4}

> ((make-odd-mapper! add-one) i4)
>
> i4

{11 2 31 4}

I know the problem needs to mutate the input list and that set-mcar! and void are apart of it......could anyone give me some reasonable lines of code to solve this? It would be useful in case anyone was wondering about mutation.....and using it to create a procedure that makes a procedure as its output....

Comment: Why do you use for every question a different nick name? And: Maybe you should read http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/ first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem as posed, to put it shortly, is impossible. The reason is, if it were possible, then you could have an expression:

```
(make-odd-mapper! add-one)
```

and this would be a function of a function, created by partial application. However, this function would have to modify its operand, and this can only be done by a macro. Therefore, the result of that function would be a macro, which is impossible, because macros don't exist as values. However, by a slight change in the definition of `make-odd-mapper!` it is possible to do something slightly different. In this case, you would use it exactly as in the original question, except that instead of saying

```
((make-odd-mapper! add-one) i4)
```

You would say

```
(make-odd-mapper! add-one i4)
```

Here is the code that does it this way:

```
;;; Applies its argument to every other element of a list.
(define map-every-other
  (lambda (function lis)
    (let map-every-other ((function function) (lis lis) (acc '()) (other #t))
      (if (null? lis)
      acc
      (map-every-other
       function
       (cdr lis)
       (append acc (list (if other (function (car lis)) (car lis))))
       (not other))))))

;;; This function does the odd mapping, but returns
;;; the new function instead of mutating the original.
(define make-odd-mapper
  (lambda (function-to-apply)
    (lambda (function)
      (lambda ()
        (map-every-other function-to-apply (function))))))

;;; This macro mutates the original function by using make-odd-mapper
(define-syntax make-odd-mapper!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ function-to-apply function)
     (begin
       (set! function
         ((make-odd-mapper function-to-apply) function))))))
```